# Calculate distance between two points in 3D space with two coordinate layers

Tags: c#, 3d

I need to calculate the distance between two points in 3D space. The coordinate system I'm using is an Int64 to get the sector, and within each sector Int32 is used to get local position. So in essence its a Int96-bit coordinate system.

Not really sure how this would work without a whole lot of if-statements checking boundaries, so there is probably a much smarter way.

Can anyone help?

PS! The precision loss in Double is acceptable. I can't use unsafe code. BigInteger is not an option as code has to run in Unity.

A sample could be:

```
public struct SectorPos
{
    public readonly Int64 X;
    public readonly Int64 Y;
    public readonly Int64 Z;

    public SectorPos(Int64 x, Int64 y, Int64 z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
public struct LocalPos
{
    public readonly Int32 X;
    public readonly Int32 Y;
    public readonly Int32 Z;

    public LocalPos(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}

struct Pos
{
    public readonly SectorPos Sector;
    public readonly LocalPos Local;

    public Pos(SectorPos sector, LocalPos local)
    {
        Sector = sector;
        Local = local;
    }
}

void Test()
{
    // Should be 1:
    Double d1 = Distance(new Pos(new SectorPos(0, 0, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MaxValue, 0, 0)), 
                         new Pos(new SectorPos(0, 1, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MinValue, 0, 0)));
    // Should be -1: (EDIT: Should be 1 of course)
    Double d2 = Distance(new Pos(new SectorPos(0, -2, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MaxValue, 0, 0)), 
                         new Pos(new SectorPos(0, -3, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MinValue, 0, 0)));
    // Should be Int32.MaxValue+1:
    Double d3 = Distance(new Pos(new SectorPos(1, 0, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MaxValue, 0, 0)), 
                         new Pos(new SectorPos(3, 0, 0), 
                                 new LocalPos(Int32.MinValue, 0, 0))); 
}
```

Comment: Why not use `BigInteger` instead of dividing the positioning to sector and local?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the code has to run on Unity too (no BigInteger). The second reason for not using BigInteger is that I need both position layers so keeping them in a struct as separate numbers is useful. I.e. only LocalPos is used for most (local) calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that `Sector X=1, Local X=int.MinValue` is roughly the same as `Sector X=0, Local X=int.MaxValue`.

This means the actual size of each sector step of `1` is `int.MaxValue*2`.

To get absolute X position, you could do `secX * int.MaxValue * 2 + locX`.

Avoid overflowing by performing those actions on `double` (instead of trying to cast to `double` at the end).

So to put this together, you can try:

```
public struct AbsolutePos
{
    private const double SEC_FACTOR = int.MaxValue * 2d;
    public readonly double X;
    public readonly double Y;
    public readonly double Z;

    public AbsolutePos(SectorPos secPos, LocalPos locPos)
    {
        X = secPos.X * SEC_FACTOR + locPos.X;
        Y = secPos.Y * SEC_FACTOR + locPos.Y;
        Z = secPos.Z * SEC_FACTOR + locPos.Z;
    }

    public double Distance(AbsolutePos pos)
    {
        // implement 3d distance calculation normally here
    }
}
```

And

```
struct Pos
{
    ...

    public AbsolutePos GetAbsPos()
    {
        return new AbsolutePos(this.Sector, this.Local);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
var pos1 = new Pos(new SectorPos(0, 0, 0), 
                   new LocalPos(Int32.MaxValue, 0, 0));
var pos2 = new Pos(new SectorPos(0, 1, 0), 
                   new LocalPos(Int32.MinValue, 0, 0));
var distance = pos1.GetAbsolutePos().Distance(pos2.GetAbsolutePos());
```

You might want to divide the final distance by `SEC_FACTOR`, depending on how you wish to look at it.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think of it this way. Fairly low CPU way of doing it, which is good. The only problem with this approach is that any calculations close to SectorPos edges (Int64.MinValue/Int64.MaxValue) will always be very inaccurate, as opposed to only being inaccurate on very high distance results.

Comment: For accuracy, simply switch to using `decimal` instead of `double`. Both can safely represent the range of numbers at hand. I rarely use `double`.

Comment: Thanks. I definitively over thought this. Decimal is 128-bit and can hold all Int64-numbers. And with that the problem should be solved. (A quick test shows Decimal capable of holding the upper and lower range of Int64.)

Comment: Yes, it can also hold the upper range of Int64 * the upper range of Int32 + the upper range of Int32 and then some.